# Private Beta Extended -- Still Going Strong

Tags: discussion

The Community Team spent some time looking at the Signal Precessing Private Beta today, and we saw a lot of good things: You have a good amount of meta activity (and you are very civil!), you are asking good, on-topic questions, and giving good answers. The DSP SE community seems to have a strong feel for what does and doesn't belong here.

However, being a niche site, Signal Processing doesn't yet have the volume of content we like to see when we move a site into public beta.  The more great content a site has when it enters public beta, the easier it is to tackle content quality problems that may be introduced by an influx of new users.

This is *not* a warning or a problem. We re-evaluate private beta sites on an ongoing basis, and have confidence that, given a little more time to increase the *quantity* of content (while maintaining your current *quality*), Signal Processing will find its way into public beta.

Comment: Sounds good! Is anyone going to any conferences anytime soon? Maybe putting up a slide at the end of a talk (or the beginning - so they can be browsing the site during your talk!!) would pull a few more users in?

Comment: What is a general expected/accepted time period for a site to remain in pubic beta? When is it considered too much or too less?